# YouTube API: When video is near end, run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, youtube, youtube-api

I'm having a problem trying to figure out how to use playback status and video length to run a function. Basically with the API, when the video starts I'm trying to get the video length and continually check when it's near the end (5 seconds). Here's one way I tried it:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        // video check logic here
        if (player.getDuration() == (player.getDuration() - 5)) {
            $('#playback-controls').fadeOut(100);
            clearInterval();
            console.log(player.getCurrentTime());
        }
        console.log(player.getCurrentTime());
    }, 1000);
```

Is setInterval the way to go about it? I'm having trouble continually checking the time and when the value is true running my command.

FYI: This is in my `if(event.data==YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)` if/else statement (which runs fine alone).

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, I'm not sure how the following is ever going to be true:

    (player.getDuration() == (player.getDuration() - 5))

Secondly, you want to use the 'less than' operator as its unlikely the the interval function is going to fire at the exact time when the duration left on the video is exactly 5 seconds. Perhaps it should read 'if (player.getCurrentTime() < (player.getDuration() - 5))...

Comment: @EdW That was another part of the issue I was having (firing at the same time). I'll try plugging that in. Thanks!